# extract data from a tablesorter table with javascript

Tags: javascript, tablesorter

I have a tablesorter table that is generated dynamically with javascript and ajax.  There are inputs for the user to change values, and when they click a button to go to the next or previous record, it needs to save the information in the table to a MySQL table.  I have looked at many of the posts on here and tried numerous examples, and I still can't get any of the data in the table to post to my PHP page to save it.
Here is a sample of the first row of my table:

```
$("#guides").append('<tr><td id="amCodeOld">'+data.amCodeOld+'</td><td><input type="text" class="qty" id="amOldQty"/></td><td>'+data.amOldPrice+
                                            '</td><td>'+data.am+
                                            '</td><td>'+data.amCodeNew+'</td><td><input type="text" class="qty" id="amNewQty"/></td><td>'+data.amNewPrice+
                                            '</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="amS" '+
                                            '"/></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="amR"'+'"/></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="amCall"'+
                                            '"/></td><td><input type="text" id="amComm" value="'+
                                            '"/></td></tr>');
```

There are more rows like this one, each for a different guide I am using.  What I need to find is the value of the inputs with id of amOldQty, amNewQty etc, and the different checkboxes.
I have buttons for Next, Prev, and Print, and when the button is clicked I am trying to call a function called save() that will get the info, and send it via ajax to another PHP page to be saved.
save() looks like this:

```
function save() {
var amOldQty 
$('#guides tr').each(function(){
alert("searching ");
       amOldQty= $(this).find('#amOldQty').val();
       if (amOldQty=='' || amOldQty== null) {
        amOldQty = "Not Showing Number";
       }
  console.log(amOldQty);  
});// END OF EACH FUNCTION
```

I have tried:

```
var amOldQty;
$('#guides tbody tr').each(function() {  
        amOldQty = $(this).find('td:nth-child(1) input').val();
    });
console.log(amOldQty);
```

and the log shows undefined.  I have also tried a more direct approach by using

```
$('#guides tbody tr').each(function() {  
        amOldQty = $(this).find('#amOldQty').val();
    });
```

and still have nothing.  I am getting the alert of Searching, but in the console.log(amQtyOld) all it shows me is "Not Showing a number".  I have even tried to have the input populated when the table first is created, and it still does not find that number.
**Update** if I add td to:

```
$(guides tr td).each(function(){...
```

It does not even give me the alert of "Searching".
How do I get all the data out of this table so I can save it?  it seems that everything I am trying should be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer seems to be to just hardcode the value of the inputs $("#amOldQty:).val() and pass them as data through ajax to my php file to save the information.  Here is the completed code in case anyone has a similar issue:

```
function save() {

function GuidesSave(){
this.update();
}

GuidesSave.prototype.list = ['am','fol','tich','book','neb','ster','c','byte','ing'];

GuidesSave.prototype.update = function(){
for( var i = 0 ; i < this.list.length ; i++ ){
var guide = this.list[i];
this[ guide + 'S' ] = $("#" + guide+'S' ).is(":checked") ? 1 : 0;
this[ guide + 'R' ] = $("#" + guide+'R' ).is(":checked") ? 1 : 0;
this[ guide + 'Call' ] = $("#" + guide+'Call' ).is(":checked") ? 1 : 0;
}// end of for loop  
}
var guides = new GuidesSave();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
        url: "poSave.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: ({po: $('#po').val(),isbn:$("#isbn13").val(),amOldQty:$("#amOldQty").val(),amNewQty:$("#amNewQty").val(),amS:guides.amS,amR:guides.amR, amCall:guides.amCall,amComm:$("#amComm").val(),
            folOldQty:$("#folOldQty").val(),folNewQty:$("#folNewQty").val(),folS:guides.folS,folR:guides.folR, folCall:guides.folCall,folComm:$("#folComm").val(),
            tichOldQty:$("#tichOldQty").val(),tichNewQty:$("#tichNewQty").val(),tichS:guides.tichS,tichR:guides.tichR, tichCall:guides.tichCall,tichComm:$("#tichComm").val(),
            bookOldQty:$("#bookOldQty").val(),bookNewQty:$("#bookNewQty").val(),bookS:guides.bookS,bookR:guides.bookR, bookCall:guides.bookCall,bookComm:$("#bookComm").val(),
            nebOldQty:$("#nebOldQty").val(),nebNewQty:$("#nebNewQty").val(),nebS:guides.nebS,nebR:guides.nebR, nebCall:guides.nebCall,nebComm:$("#nebComm").val(),
            sterOldQty:$("#sterOldQty").val(),sterNewQty:$("#sterNewQty").val(),sterS:guides.sterS,sterR:guides.sterR, sterCall:guides.sterCall,sterComm:$("#sterComm").val(),
            cheggOldQty:$("#cOldQty").val(),cheggNewQty:$("#cNewQty").val(),cheggS:guides.cS,cheggR:guides.cR, cheggCall:guides.cCall,cheggComm:$("#cComm").val(),
            byteOldQty:$("#byteOldQty").val(),byteNewQty:$("#byteNewQty").val(),byteS:guides.byteS,byteR:guides.byteR, byteCall:guides.byteCall,byteComm:$("#byteComm").val(),
            ingOldQty:$("#ingOldQty").val(),ingNewQty:$("#ingNewQty").val(),ingS:guides.ingS,ingR:guides.ingR, ingCall:guides.ingCall,ingComm:$("#ingComm").val(),
            qty1: $('#topqty').val(),price1: $('#topVal').html(),comp1:$('#topCo').html(),
            qty2: $('#secqty').val(),price2: $('#secVal').html(),comp2: $('#secCo').html(),
            qty3: $('#thrqty').val(),price3: $('#thrVal').html(),comp3: $('#thrCo').html()}),
        success: function(data){
        }
});
}// END OF SAVE FUNCTION
```

The GuideSave function loops through all the check boxes (27 different ones) to see whichones are checked so I can save them as either a 1 or 0 and then have them checked or not when the record is recalled.

Answer (score 0):

If your users use [browsers that support contenteditable elements](http://caniuse.com/#search=contenteditable), then you can check out the [contenteditable widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-editable.html) I have available for my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/).

If you don't want to use contenteditable elements, then you can try the following code (copied and modified from the contenteditable demo, but not tested)

```
var $table = $('table');

$table.children('tbody').on('change', 'input', function(event){
  var $input = $(this),
    $cell = $input.closest('td'),

    newContent = $input.val(),
    cellIndex = $cell[0].cellIndex, // there shouldn't be any colspans in the tbody
    rowIndex = $this.closest('tr').attr('id'); // unique row id

  // update tablesorter
  $table.trigger("updateCell", [$cell]);

  $.post("mysite.php", {
    "row"     : rowIndex,
    "cell"    : cellIndex,
    "content" : newContent
  });

});
```

Hopefully, you're also using an [input parser](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/parsers/parser-input-select.js) for that column.

Comment: This looks like it would be great if i wanted to save the info everymtime a cell was updated, but there are numerous cells that can be changed, so I am trying to save it once when they click on a next, prev, or print button.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what or how you are wanting to present the data.  However, [here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2Lq7wa9/20/) that does what it appears you desire.

The function `createRowsForTesting()` just creates the rows in the table and populates the `<input>` fields to make testing easier.

The function `getDataFromTable()` walks the rows of a <table>, or all <tables>, sending the data you said you wanted to the console. From your own answer to this question it became clear that you really wanted to access many more <input> elements than was mentioned in your question.  Thus, this this function now builds an array of Objects which contain key:value pairs for the data in <input> fields.  There is one Object in the array for each row. The array is returned to the calling function.

The function `wrapGetDataFromTable()` wraps `getDataFromTable()` providing the table ID, that we are only looking in rows within the <tbody> tag and that we want output to the console.  The array returned by `getDataFromTable()` is output so we can see the data structure.  The function is set up to run each time you press the [print to console] button.

For a table that looks like (with header row):
[image: Test table]

The output is:

```
amOldQty=amOldQty0_text amNewQty=amNewQty0_text amS=on  amR=off amCall=off  amComm=amComm0_text 
amOldQty=amOldQty1_text amNewQty=amNewQty1_text amS=off amR=on  amCall=off  amComm=amComm1_text 
amOldQty=amOldQty2_text amNewQty=amNewQty2_text amS=off amR=off amCall=on   amComm=amComm2_text 

The array of row input data objects is:
[0] Object { amOldQty="amOldQty0_text", amNewQty="amNewQty0_text", amS="on", more...}
        amOldQty:   "amOldQty0_text"
        amNewQty:   "amNewQty0_text"
        amS:        "on"
        amR:        "off"
        amCall:     "off"
        amComm:     "amComm0_text"

[1] Object { amOldQty="amOldQty1_text", amNewQty="amNewQty1_text", amS="off", more...}
        amOldQty:   "amOldQty1_text"
        amNewQty:   "amNewQty1_text"
        amS:        "off"
        amR:        "on"
        amCall:     "off"
        amComm:     "amComm1_text"

[2]  Object { amOldQty="amOldQty2_text", amNewQty="amNewQty2_text", amS="off", more...}
        amOldQty:   "amOldQty2_text"
        amNewQty:   "amNewQty2_text"
        amS:        "off"
        amR:        "off"
        amCall:     "on"
        amComm:     "amComm2_text"
```

JavaScript:

```
/**
 * Runs through a table getting the values from <input> fields.
 * It only looks in the <tbody>, not the <thead>
 * @param  tableId
 *         The DOM ID of the table from which we desire to obtain the
 *         input values.
 *         If tableId is not a string, then look in all table rows in all tables.
 * @param  keyAttr
 *         The attribute of the <input> which contains the value which will
 *         be used as the key for the key:value pair within the Object returned.
 *         This needs to be a value which is unique, wihin the table row.
 *         A normal use would be "id".
 *         If a value is duplicated a message is sent to the console and only
 *         the last value is kept.
 *         The default is "id".
 * @param  justBody
 *         If true, look only within the <tbody> tag, not any other part of
 *         the table (e.g. <thead>).
 *         The default is true.
 * @param  includeBlank
 *         Boolean indicating if the returned array should contain an entry for
 *         rows which are found to be blank.
 *         The default is true.
 * @param  consoleOutput
 *         Send a line to the console with the key:value pairs separated by
 *         tabs for each row.
 *         The default is false.
 * @return Object
 *         Returns an Array of Objects with key:value pairs for the rows.
 *         If there were no <input>
 * Copyright 2014 by Makyen.
 * Released under the MPL 2.0. http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.
 */
function getDataFromTable(tableId, keyAttr, justBody, includeBlank, consoleOutput) {
    //This assumes that within the row each input has a unique attribute keyAttr.
    //Set defaults:
    var tableSelector = (typeof tableId === "string") ? "#" + tableId : "table";
    keyAttr = (typeof keyAttr === "string") ? keyAttr : "id";
    includeBlank = (typeof includeBlank === "boolean") ? includeBlank : true;
    justBody = (typeof justBody === "boolean") ? justBody : true;
    consoleOutput = (typeof consoleOutput === "boolean") ? consoleOutput : false;

    var bodySelector = (justBody) ? " tbody" : "";
    var toReturn = [];
    var selector = tableSelector + bodySelector + ' tr';
    $(selector).each(function () {
        var inputs = {};
        $(this).find('input').each(function () {
            //Get the value for all inputs on this line.
            var attrValue = $(this).attr(keyAttr);
            if (typeof inputs[attrValue] !== "undefined") {
                console.log("Warning: When attempting to get data from the table id=" //
                            + tableId + " the value of the key attribute, " + keyAttr //
                            + ", was not unique for value=" + attrValue);
            }
            //Get the value of the <input>.
            if ($(this).is(':checkbox')) {
                //Special case the checkboxes because .val() does not return
                //the correct informaiton for them.
                //First indicate that all checkboxes are off.
                inputs[attrValue] = "off";
                //Specifically determine if the current one is checked.
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    inputs[attrValue] = "on";
                }
            } else {
                //Add this input to the object
                inputs[attrValue] = $(this).val();
            }
        });
        var inputKeys = Object.keys(inputs);
        if (inputKeys.length > 0) {
            //There were <input> tags on this row.
            var outputText = "";
            if (consoleOutput) {
                inputKeys.forEach(function (value) {
                    outputText += value + "=" + inputs[value] + "\t";
                });
                console.log(outputText);
            }
            toReturn.push(inputs);
        } else {
            //No <input> tags on this row
            if (includeBlank) {
                if (consoleOutput) {
                    console.log("A row without <input> tags was found.");
                }
                toReturn.push(inputs);
            }
        }
    });
    return toReturn;
}

function wrapGetDataFromTable() {
    //This wraper is so the getDataFromTable() function remains
    //  generic.  The wrapper merely defines which table from which to
    //  get the data,
    //  the attribute to use for unique keys = "id"
    //  to look only in the <tbody>
    //  to not include an object for the lines which are blank
    //  and output the row data to the console.
    var toReturn = getDataFromTable("guides", "id", true, false, true);
    if (typeof console.dir === "function") {
        //Make sure console.dir() exists prior to using it.
        console.log("The array of row input data objects is:");
        console.dir(toReturn); //Let us see the Object in the console for checking.
    }
    return toReturn;
}
$('#to-console-button').click(wrapGetDataFromTable);


//The rest is setup for creating the table header and rows.
//It is only for testing.

function createRowsForTesting() {
    const numRowsToCreate = 3;

    var i;
    var data = {
        amCodeOld: "amCodeOld",
        amOldPrice: "amOldPrice",
        am: "am",
        amCodeNew: "amCodeNew",
        amNewPrice: "amNewPrice"
    };

    //Create the table
    //First add a header.
    $("#guides thead").append('<tr><th>amCodeOld_H</th>' //
                              + '<th>amOldQty_H</th>'    //
                              + '<th>amOldPrice_H</th>'  //
                              + '<th>am_H</th>'          //
                              + '<th>amCodeNew_H</th>'   //
                              + '<th>amNewQty_H</th>'    //
                              + '<th>amNewPrice_H</th>'  //
                              + '<th>amS_H</th>'         //
                              + '<th>amR_H</th>'         //
                              + '<th>amCall_H</th>'      //
                              + '<th>amComm_H</th></tr>');
    //Now the body rows.
    for (i = 0; i < numRowsToCreate; i++) {
        //From stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998929/extract-data-from-a-tablesorter-table-with-javascript
        $("#guides tbody").append('<tr><td id="amCodeOld">'+data.amCodeOld+'</td><td><input type="text" class="qty" id="amOldQty"/></td><td>'+data.amOldPrice+ //
                                            '</td><td>'+data.am+ //
                                            '</td><td>'+data.amCodeNew+'</td><td><input type="text" class="qty" id="amNewQty"/></td><td>'+data.amNewPrice+ //
                                            '</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="amS" '+ //
                                            '"/></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="amR"'+'"/></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="amCall"'+ //
                                            '"/></td><td><input type="text" id="amComm" value="'+ //
                                            '"/></td></tr>');
    }
    //*
    //Fake having the table filled in, as I am tired of entering the input
    //You have to try it without this, but with manual input in order to truly verify
    var row = 0;
    $('#guides tbody tr').each(function () {
        $(this).find('#amOldQty').val("amOldQty" + row + "_text");
        $(this).find('#amNewQty').val("amNewQty" + row + "_text");
        $(this).find('#amComm').val("amComm" + row + "_text");
        row++;
    });
    //*/
}



createRowsForTesting();
```

HTML:

```
<table class="tablesorter" id="guides">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" id="to-console-button">print to console</button>
<!-- values to use to fill input:
amOldQty0_text
amOldQty1_text
amNewQty0_text
amNewQty1_text
amComm0_text
amComm1_text -->
```

Note: The selector (`$("#guides").append('<tr>...`) used in your line to add the table row to the table might be your problem.  It currently adds your rows as the last elements in the `<table>`, not the last in the `<tbody>`.  While the browser should compensate for this, it is possible that it is not doing so in your environment. Try `$("#guides tbody").append('<tr>...`

However, it appears more likely that the issue is a header row (or a row without input cells) in the `<tbody>`.  The code now accounts for this possibility.

Comment: Hi Makyen, thanks for putting so much time into this, however, when I try your suggestion, I get undefined for amOldQty and off for the 3 check boxes.  I copied your printToConsole function exactly, and manually inputted a number into the amOldQty box.

Comment: Updated for the other two inputs. There was a bug in the table creation code, not the printing.-- Ok. given you seeing problems on your side, but I am not seeing any, we need to track down the difference. Are you seeing the undefined/off problem on the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2Lq7wa9/11/), or in your own code? If you have not tried the JSFiddle, or if it has not worked for you, please try it again. What OS & Browser are you using? What version of jQuery/tablesorter? What tablesorter add-ons are you using? What is your *exact* call to tablesorter to set up sorting?

Comment: I assume you have a header line for the table, please provide that also. These things will help make it possible to duplicate your issue.

Comment: I have updated the code to account for the possibility of header rows in the `<tbody>` (actually any rows without the `<input id="amOldQty">`). Such non-input rows in the `<tbod>` would result in the `undefined` which you have reported.  It may be the problem.

Comment: I just solved my issue by just hardcoding the value without using the .each().  For some reason when I try to assign it a value, it would always come up as undefined.  Your jsfiddle seemed to work fine for me when I tried it.  There are non-input rows in the table body, but I use that function to update a total by using the .each() and a class of qty, so I am not sure why it does not work here.  Thanks again for all the help, I will award you the bounty for all of your hard work.

Comment: Thank you (in advance). From your own answer, it became clear that the list of input field identifiers in your question was significantly simplified from your actual use case and that you needed a generalized function that dealt with any number of input fields in a row.  I have updated the code to provide that.  It should also make the code useable by others rather than special purpose for just the input IDs you specified. The function now returns an array of Objects with key:value pairs for the <input> field ID:value.